# How can I speed up this haskell lastDigits x y function?

Tags: performance, haskell, functional-programming

I have a haskell assignment in which i have to create a function lastDigit x y of 2 arguments that calculates the sum of all [x^x | (0..x)], mine is too slow and i need to speed it up. Anyone has any ideas??

```
list  :: Integral x=>x->[x]
list 0 = []
list x = list(div x 10) ++ [(mod x 10)] 

sqrall :: Integer->[Integer]
sqrall x y = [mod (mod x 10^y)^x 10^y  | x <- [1..x]]

lastDigits :: Integer -> Int -> [Integer]
lastDigits x y = drop (length((list(sum (sqrall x y))))-y) (list(sum (sqrall x)))
```

Comment: Hint: you do not need to calculate the entire number. You can always sum up the last numbers. Furthermore you can make a special `pow` function that calculates the last digit of `x^x`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But i'll still have to calculate x^x which is what actually wastes time

Comment: no not at all, note that `(x * y) mod n = (x mod n) * (y mod n) mod n`, so you can simply always keep the numbers in the 0-100 range and use an algorithm that works in *O(log x)* time.

Comment: for the last digit, you can even do it in constant time by analysing the length of the *cycle* of the last digit.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I dont get how this (x * y) mod n = (x mod n) * (y mod n) mod n remark will help me, can u tell me where in my code should i implement it

Comment: try to construct a `pow10` function that uses explicit recursion to calculate the `x^x` value. Use this hint to only work with numbers in the 0-100 range.

Comment: You can also take a look at http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/src/Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Modular.html#powMod

Answer (score 5):

The main reason this will take too long is because you calculate the entire number of `x^x`, which scales *super exponentially*. This means that even for very small `x`, it will still take a considerable amount of time.

The point is however that you do not need to calculate the entire number. Indeed, you can make use of the fact that *x×y* mod *n = (x* mod *n) × (y* mod *n)* mod *n*. For example Haskell's [**`arithmoi`** package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/Math-NumberTheory-Powers-Modular.html#v:powMod) makes use of this [[src]](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/arithmoi-0.10.0.0/docs/src/Math.NumberTheory.Powers.Modular.html#powMod):

> ```
> powMod :: (Integral a, Integral b) => a -> b -> a -> a
> powMod x y m
>   | m <= 0    = error "powModInt: non-positive modulo"
>   | y <  0    = error "powModInt: negative exponent"
>   | otherwise = f (x `rem` m) y 1 `mod` m
>   where
>     f _ 0 acc = acc
>     f b e acc = f (b * b `rem` m) (e `quot` 2)
>       (if odd e then (b * acc `rem` m) else acc)
> ```

We can make a specific version for modulo 10 with:

```
pow10 :: Integral i => i -> i
pow10 x = go x x
    where go 0 _ = 1
          go i j | odd i = rec * j `mod` 10
                 | otherwise = rec
               where rec = go (div i 2) ((j*j) `mod` 10)
```

This then matches `` x^x `mod` 10 ``, except that we do not need to calculate the entire number:

```
Prelude> map pow10 [1 .. 20]
[1,4,7,6,5,6,3,6,9,0,1,6,3,6,5,6,7,4,9,0]
Prelude> [x^x `mod` 10 | x <- [1..20]]
[1,4,7,6,5,6,3,6,9,0,1,6,3,6,5,6,7,4,9,0]
```

Now that we have that, we can also calculate the the sum of the two last digits with integers that range to at most 18:

```
sum10 :: Int -> Int -> Int
sum10 x y = (x + y) `mod` 10
```

we thus can calculate the last digit with:

```
import Data.List(foldl')

lastdigit :: Int -> Int
lastdigit x = foldl' sum10 0 (map pow10 [0 .. x])
```

For example for `x = 26`, we get:

```
Prelude Data.List> lastdigit 26
4
Prelude Data.List> sum [ x^x | x <- [0 .. 26] ]
6246292385799360560872647730684286774
```

I keep it as an exercise to generalize the above to calculate it for the last *y* digits. As long as *y* is relatively small, this will be efficient, since then the numbers never take huge amounts of memory. Furthermore if the numbers have an upper bound, addition, multiplication, etc. are done in constant time. If you however use an `Integer`, then the numbers can be arbitrary large, and thus operations like addition are not constant.